# Missing Classes in Authorize.net PHP SDK

Tags: php, sdk, authorize.net

I'm trying to generate a custom report from Authorize.net using their API but cannot get the SDK to load without errors.

I created a post on the developer board [HERE](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Fatal-error-Class-Goetas-Xsd-XsdToPhp-Jms-Handler/td-p/54698) as well as sending an email request to their support team.  The issue was supposed to have been fixed with a temporary patch [HERE](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/commit/d63a785803647e4d137a56cecb7c150e15c32fef). But the errors persist.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to work around this issue?

My Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

/* autoload through composer */
//require 'vendor/autoload.php';

/* autoload through git clone */
//require 'git/sdk-php/autoload.php';

/* autoload through .zip download */
require 'download/sdk-php-master/autoload.php';

use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController; 

function getSettledBatchList($startDate, $endDate) {
    $api_id         = "MY_API_ID";
    $account_key    = "MY_ACCOUNT_KEY";
    $start_dt       = new DateTime($startDate);
    $end_dt         = new DateTime($endDate);

    $merchAuth      = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchAuth->setName($api_id);
    $merchAuth->setTransactionKey($account_key);

    $request        = new AnetAPI\GetSettledBatchListRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchAuth);
    $request->setIncludeStatistics(true);
    $request->setFirstSettlementDate($start_dt);
    $request->setLastSettlementDate($end_dt);

    $controller     = new AnetController\GetSettledBatchListController($request);
    $response       = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

    if(($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")){
        /* Do Nothing For Now */
    }else{
        $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
        echo "Response : " . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . "  " .$errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";
    }
    return $response;
}

$api_response   = getSettledBatchList('2016-05-01T00:00:00Z', '2016-05-10T00:00:00Z');
var_dump($api_response); 

?>
```

The Errors:

```
/* Loaded with git clone https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php.git */

Warning: include(sdk-php/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in sdk-php/autoload.php on line 16 

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/sdk-php/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in sdk-php/autoload.php on line 16 

Fatal error: Class 'JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type' not found in /sdk-php/lib/net/authorize/util/SensitiveDataConfigType.php on line 6


/* Loaded by downloading .zip from github page */

Warning: include(/sdk-php-master/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /sdk-php-master/autoload.php on line 16 

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/sdk-php-master/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /sdk-php-master/autoload.php on line 16 

Fatal error: Class 'JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type' not found in /sdk-php-master/lib/net/authorize/util/SensitiveDataConfigType.php on line 6


/* Loaded with Composer using recommended composer.json */

Fatal error: Class 'Goetas\Xsd\XsdToPhp\Jms\Handler\BaseTypesHandler' not found in /vendor/authorizenet/authorizenet/lib/net/authorize/api/controller/base/ApiOperationBase.php on line 82
```

I'm open to all ideas at this point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, and I realized that the problem is that I was using `require` on the wrong `autoload.php` and I think you're doing that too.

You probably have figured it by now but in case someone else has this problem the solution is this:

You have to load/require the `autoload.php` that's inside the `vendor` folder, not the one inside the sdk (root) folder.

Comment: Kind of related, but I had a monolithic repository and was trying to run tests higher up, which were finding the nested tests that belonged to another project, thus that project had its own composer file and tests that were irrelevant to the scope of the tests I was trying to run. I ended up excluding the directory from my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake.  The patch was to the composer.json file that updated the required-dev version of Goetas.  Did not realize I needed to update my composer.json before running composer update.

[Updated composer.json Language](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/commit/d63a785803647e4d137a56cecb7c150e15c32fef)